# Increasing size of lines in ggplot mean cumulative function plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, recurrent

I am using the reReg package to create mean cumulative function plots.
but I am unable to change the size of lines inside the plot.

is there anyway to increase the line width?
[image]

```
library(reReg)
data(readmission, package = "frailtypack")
readmission <- subset(readmission, !(id %in% c(60, 109, 280)))
mcf0 <- mcf(Recur(t.start %2% t.stop, id, event, death) ~ sex, data = readmission)
p<- plot(mcf0, conf.int = TRUE)

p + theme_bw(base_size = 20)
```

Thanks for reading

Comment: Try `plot(mcf0, conf.int = TRUE, lwd = 2)`

Comment: If that doesn't work TimoKvamme, consider putting in a bug report to the author: the code references `ctrl <- plotEvents.control()` and then uses `geom_step(..., size=ctrl$lwd)`, but `lwd` is neither an argument to `plotEvents.control` nor does it allow additional arguments. It seems (with debugging and testing) that the `plot*` functions there are effectively doing `size=NULL`, which while it _should_ emit a message ("Please use `linewidth` instead"), it does not adversely affect the plot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `ggplot_build` to change the `linewidth` in each layer with `lapply` like this (I used big linewidth to show result):

```r
library(reReg)
library(ggplot2)
library(frailtypack)
data(readmission, package = "frailtypack")
readmission <- subset(readmission, !(id %in% c(60, 109, 280)))
mcf0 <- mcf(Recur(t.start %2% t.stop, id, event, death) ~ sex, data = readmission)
p <- plot(mcf0, conf.int = TRUE) + theme_bw(base_size = 20) 

q <- ggplot_build(p)

q$data = lapply(q$data, \(x) {
  x$linewidth = 3
  x
})

q <- ggplot_gtable(q)
plot(q)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-04-06 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Different linewidth:

```r
library(reReg)
library(ggplot2)
library(frailtypack)

p <- plot(mcf0, conf.int = TRUE) + theme_bw(base_size = 20) 

q <- ggplot_build(p)

q$data = lapply(q$data, \(x) {
  x$linewidth = 1
  x
})

q <- ggplot_gtable(q)
plot(q)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-04-06 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you. that gets the job done